# Not able to run react app in node application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js

I am working on a node application where I need to load a react app.

This is my structure:

```
 - backend
 - public
    - index.html
    - assets
      - index.js
 - src
    - controllers
    - routes
 - frontend
```

I am trying to static upload index.html files from my node app.

This is what I am trying to do

```js
import { Router } from 'express';
import * as path from 'path'; // Import path module to work with file paths

import Cache from './../providers/Cache';

import WorkflowController from '../controllers/Workflow';

const router = Router();
const cache = Cache.cache;

// router.get('/workflow', cache(10), WorkflowController.index);
router.get('/workflow', cache(10), (req, res) => {
    console.log('Workflow page');
    const indexPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', '..' ,'public', 'index.html');
    return res.sendFile(indexPath);
});

export default router;
```

I am able to run html file but it does not open the index.js file as my index.js file is at this location on browser - http://localhost:4040/public/assets/index-73Edh7Y0.js

But it actually searches at this location in network tab -

[image]

Can anyone guide me what is missing here -

Comment: Am I right in assuming that your index.html has a `<script>` element in it that refers to the index-73Edh7Y0.js file?  If so, may we see it?  Do you refer to it by a full path or not?  Your page is served at the endpoint `/workflow`, so `<script src="foo">` would look for `/workflow/foo`

Comment: What is the path to `index.js` specified in your html file?

Comment: This is the script tag
<script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index-73Edh7Y0.js"></script>

And this html is generated from react file

Comment: Also, which build tool are you using? `vite`, `create-react-app`, or something else?

Comment: I am using vite

Comment: I think your best bet will be to try to modify some of the build options until you get the results you want: https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options.

Comment: Is there any other way i can load my react application inside node ?

Comment: Typically you serve your react app as a static site from s3, for example. Then you can call backend API from your react app.